# Finding matrix entries to keep vectors constant

Tags: linear-algebra

Let vectors $\vec{v} \in R^n$ and $\vec{w} \in R^m$ be constant and let a matrix $A \in R^{m\times n}$ be the linear map between them such that $\vec{v} = A\vec{w}$.  Now, I want to find all values of the entries in $A$ for which the two vectors remain constant.  How do I do that, or at least, what should I be looking for?

Comment: I am confused. Are you defining $v = Aw$?

Comment: Yes, I want to find A such that v and w are constant. I suspect there is a family of such matrices A. How would I find that family?

Comment: Ah. I see what you are saying now. Given two vectors $v$ and $w$, you want to find all matrices $A$ such that $Aw = v$. Sorry, your question confused me for some reason...

Comment: No problem you put it much more succinctly. Thanks for that

Comment: So, I am not sure what kind of description you are looking for - maybe you could try some examples? But one thing you do know is that if $A'$ is another matrix such that $A'w = v$ then you know that $(A-A')w = 0$ and hence $w$ has to be in the kernel of $A-A'$.

Comment: You have $m$ and $n$ mixed up between vectors and matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A w = v$ for given fixed $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ means we have $m$ equations
$$
v_i 
= \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} w_j
= \sum_{j=1}^n w_j a_{ij}
$$
in $mn$ unknowns $a_{ij}$. The last step should emphasize that the roles of system matrix and vector of unknowns have switched here: $w$ induces the matrix of the linear system, $A$ is the unknown vector of matrix coefficients.

So we have at least $mn-m = m(n-1)$ degrees of freedom to choose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

**Example:**

$m = 2$, $n = 3$:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & w_1 & w_2 & w_3  \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_{11} \\
a_{12} \\
a_{13} \\
a_{21} \\
a_{22} \\
a_{23} \\
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
v_1 \\
v_2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
or as augmented matrix suited to perform Gauss-Jordan elimination
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc|c}
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & v_1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & v_2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
we immeadiatly see that we have $4$ degrees of freedom to choose $A$ if $w \ne 0$, otherwise we have all $6$ degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

Given the setup, I’m assuming that the constraint is actually $A\vec v=\vec w$.

Choose a basis $B$ of $\mathbb R^m$ that includes $\vec v$, say as the $j$th element. The matrix of your linear map relative to this basis will have $\vec w$ as its $j$th column, but can have anything at all for its other columns. The matrix $A$ is then this matrix after a change of basis to the standard basis.

That’s a lot of leeway, but this reflects the fact that requiring $A\vec v=\vec w$ doesn’t constrain the map very much.

Answer (score 0):

First it looks like you have reversed the two vectors. By looking at the matrix dimension the linear map should be $w=Av$.
Anyway, you want express each component of $w$ in terms of a linear combination of all the components of $v$:
$$w_i = a_i^Tv = a_{i1} v_1 + ... +  a_{in} v_n,\quad \forall i=1,...,m$$
where $a^T_i$ denotes the $i$-th row of $A$.

Of course there is not a unique solution to this problem.